# Using spring integration v5.5.14 lots of queued task are increasing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

after upgrading to spring boot version v2.7.1 we are seeing that there are lots of queued task, we never had seen such queued task increasing in the last version we were using v2.2.2.
Our team has tried to check the things in v2.7.1 but couldn't found anything in this version.
Can anyone please review the code and let us know what we are missing or have written wrong that is causing the issue. We are using spring integration to pull emails from client server and for that we have add a taskexecutor to have concurrent polling.

Versions that we use:
Spring Boot = 2.7.1
Spring Integration = 5.5.14

Earlier we were using:
Spring Boot = 2.2.2 release
Spring Integration = 5.2.3 release

I've attached the code below.

```
Configuration class for Imap Integration

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class ImapIntegrationConfig {

  private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Autowired
  public ImapIntegrationConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  @Bean("mailTaskExecutor")
  public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor mailTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(100);
    taskExecutor.setTaskDecorator(new SecurityAwareTaskDecorator(applicationContext));
    taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    taskExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return taskExecutor;
  }

  @Bean("imapMailChannel")
  public ExecutorChannelSpec imapMailChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.executor(mailTaskExecutor());
  }

  @Bean
  public HeaderMapper<MimeMessage> mailHeaderMapper() {
    return new DefaultMailHeaderMapper();
  }
}
```

ImapListener Class to register the flow

```
public void registerImapFlow(ImapSetting imapSetting) {
    ImapMailReceiver mailReceiver = createImapMailReceiver(imapSetting);

    // create the flow for an email process
    //@formatter:off
    StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
      .from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter(mailReceiver),
        consumer -> consumer.autoStartup(true)
                            .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofMinutes(2))
                                           .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                                           .errorHandler(t -> logger.error("Error while polling emails for address " + imapSetting.getUsername(), t))
                                           .maxMessagesPerPoll(10)))
      .enrichHeaders(Map.of(CONCERN_CODE, imapSetting.getConcernCode(), IMAP_CONFIG_ID, imapSetting.getImapSettingId()))
      .channel(imapMailChannel).get();
    //@formatter:on

    // give the bean a unique name to avoid clashes with multiple imap settings
    String flowId = concernIdentifier.getConcernIdentifier() + "-" + imapSetting.getImapSettingId();
    IntegrationFlowContext.IntegrationFlowRegistration existingFlow = integrationFlowContext.getRegistrationById(flowId);
    if (existingFlow != null) {
      // destroy the previous beans
      existingFlow.destroy();
    }
    // register the new flow
    integrationFlowContext.registration(flow).id(flowId).useFlowIdAsPrefix().register();
   }
```

Process message method

```
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "imapMailChannel")
  public void processMessage(Message<?> message) throws InvalidMessageException {
    String concern = (String) message.getHeaders().get(CONCERN_CODE);
    if (isEmpty(concern)) {
      logger.error("Received null concern!");
    }
    Long imapConfigId = (Long) message.getHeaders().get(IMAP_CONFIG_ID);

    String logMessage = null;
    String messageId = null;
    try {
      Object payload = message.getPayload();
      if (payload instanceof MimeMultipart) {
        //.......................//
      }
      else if (payload instanceof String) {
        //......................//
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Error while processing " + logMessage, e);
      if (concern != null) {
        metricUtil.emailFailed(concern);
      }
      throw new MaxxtonException("CCM-MessageID: Exception in processMessage() method", e, MessageErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_PROCESS_EMAIL);
    }
    metricUtil.emailProcessed(concern);
  }
```

ImapMailReceiver method

```
    private ImapMailReceiver createImapMailReceiver(ImapSetting imapSettings) {
    String url = String.format(imapSettings.getImapUrl(), URLEncoder.encode(imapSettings.getUsername(), UTF_8), URLEncoder.encode(imapSettings.getPassword(), UTF_8));
    ImapMailReceiver receiver = new ImapMailReceiver(url);
    receiver.setSimpleContent(true);

    Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
    mailProperties.put("mail.debug", "false");

    mailProperties.put("mail.imap.connectionpoolsize", "5");
    mailProperties.put("mail.imap.fetchsize", 4194304);
    mailProperties.put("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", 15000);
    mailProperties.put("mail.imap.timeout", 30000);

    mailProperties.put("mail.imaps.connectionpoolsize", "5");
    mailProperties.put("mail.imaps.fetchsize", 4194304);
    mailProperties.put("mail.imaps.connectiontimeout", 15000);
    mailProperties.put("mail.imaps.timeout", 30000);

    receiver.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);
    receiver.setSearchTermStrategy(this::notSeenTerm);
    receiver.setAutoCloseFolder(false);
    receiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(false);
    receiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);
    receiver.setHeaderMapper(mailHeaderMapper);
    receiver.setEmbeddedPartsAsBytes(false);
    return receiver;
  }
```

[Added a screenshot taken from Grafana of active and queued task when we have upgraded to SP v2.7.1 and SI v5.5.14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9IJs.png)

Answer (score 0):

At a glance it all looks OK. Unless you really don't close that folder manually elsewhere since you use `receiver.setAutoCloseFolder(false);`

There is no reason in that `.taskExecutor(taskExecutor)` since you use `MessageChannels.executor(mailTaskExecutor())` immediately after producing message from the `Mail.imapInboundAdapter()`.

I remember that in Gitter I suggested you to check how it works with the `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=10` placed into the `application.properties`. This is the only obvious difference between the mentioned versions: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.spring-integration.

Your screenshot doesn't prove that the problem is exactly with Spring Integration. Perhaps tasks are queued somehow by the tool which exports metrics to Graphana. I believe you have upgraded not just Spring Integration in your project...

Comment: yes, we have upgraded spring boot and other dependencies but the service which is creating the issue is having spring integration dependency.  "Perhaps tasks are queued somehow by the tool which exports metrics to Graphana" -> if u check at the bottom of the screenshot u will notice that the queued task "mailTaskExecutor" this is the taskexecutor that is used in in Mail inbound adapter.

Comment: Hi Artem, about this line " Unless you really don't close that folder manually elsewhere since you use receiver.setAutoCloseFolder(false);", in the code we don't close the folder, but we usually use to get the below exception "org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE Connection closed.
 at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.doReceive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:74)" I

Comment: Below or above? You use the same executor also in the channel. Consider to remove on of those references for an executor. How does it work if you don’t decorate tasks for security? What if you change your service activator to something very simple like just a log message? I mean it looks this your code is blocking somewhere to let the tasks to pile.

Comment: I have set a @Qualifier("mailTaskExecutor") ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor in constructor so only one executor bean we have

Comment: and is there any way to solve this exception : "org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE Connection closed. at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.doReceive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:74)"

Comment: That's not what I mean. You use the same `TaskExecutor` in different subsequent steps. My point that you don't need an executor for the poller if you use an `ExecutorChannel` as an output of that mail channel adapter. Re. `FolderClosedException` - we need to see more stack trace. And probably this deserves its own SO thread.

Comment: if I understand correctly then u are pointing this two locations,  
  `1. @Bean("imapMailChannel")
  public ExecutorChannelSpec imapMailChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.executor(mailTaskExecutor());
  }`                                                                                                                                   `2.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofMinutes(2))
                                           .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)`

Comment: I should not use same executor in both the places right?

Comment: You should not use only one task execution approach: or from the poller , or in the `ExecutorChannel`. With the current one you just move message from one thread to another where it has been just moved from a scheduler thread.

Comment: u mean executor should be used one of the place?

Comment: Right. Or channel or poller , but not both. Semantically they do the same for your current config